# Address Book Unique Phone Numbers

Tags: ios, addressbook

Is there any library out there that can take Address Book contacts with phone numbers and convert them to the unique phone number with international country calling code.

This would involve

1. Converting local phone numbers to international, once given a particular country code.
2. Recognise and maintain existing international numbers

This is to achieve something similar to whatsapp does, by using full phone numbers as usernames and converting users contacts to full phone numbers to check which of your friends are on whatsapp.

I am about to attempt it myself, but I feel there will be a lot of work in catering for the various different phone number configurations out there, so any head starts would be useful.

Comment: Hey, I did find one, I think it may have been this one or similar. It was a port from another language... https://github.com/iziz/libPhoneNumber-iOS